# Trying to run a python script on startup on my raspberry pi

Tags: linux, bash, python, raspberry-pi, crontab

I've googled how to do this but I don't understand enough about linux to be able to interpret the answers.

I ssh into my pi and log in using the user 'pi' and the password I set.

Then I type `sudo -s` which seems important

I type `cd /home` to go to my home folder, and there I created a file called `myscript.py` which contains an infinite loop. It collects information from a usb port device and sends it to a server. The only function of the pi is to do this task as that's the reason I installed it.

I can't run it in the ssh because sometimes my pc reboots or I close it and forget to open it again. So what I wanted to do was make it run when the pi is powered up.

To do this I experimentally made a file called `myscriptlauncher.sh` following a variety of online instructions and put this into it:

```
#!/bin/sh
# myscriptlauncher.sh

cd /home
python myscript.py
```

I don't know what the first two lines mean exactly but that's what I put in.

Then I typed `crontab -e` which opened up a window with a bunch of text in. At the bottom I wrote this:

```
@reboot sh /home/myscriptlauncher.sh
```

I rebooted but it seems that my script did not run. I am not really sure what I am doing just flailing in the dark. I wonder if anyone could help me to understand what I need to do.

I also tried `chmod +x myscriptlauncher.sh` and rebooting but this did not do anything either.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by not typing `sudo -s` and then `crontab -e` seemed to run as the 'pi' user instead of root. Then it seemed to work. Even though the pi is not configured to log on at startup.

Possibly it relates to the /home/ directory, I do not know.